# DoTween. how to call a function when Tween has finished?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I couldn't find anything in their documentation but I'm really stuck with how to call a function, once DoTween has finished the tween. :/ Does anyone know?

I tried this but I get an error onComplete does not take an argument.

```
unlocked.DOSizeDelta(Vector2.one, .3f).SetEase(Ease.InBack).onComplete(ResetUnlock);


private void ResetUnlock()
{
    print("dosomething");
}
```

Comment: Beware the _[train wreck anti-pattern](https://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck)_

Comment: @MickyD unfortunatelly it is how [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php) works though ;) Of curse you could split them up in multiple lines though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnComplete` is just a `TweenCallback` delegate. So you just need to assign it like so.

```
unlocked.DOSizeDelta(Vector2.one, .3f).SetEase(Ease.InBack).onComplete = ResetUnlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

as JDormer mentioned its a `TweenCallback` delegate.
You can use a lambda function (anonymous delegate) with no parameters to call your `ResetUnlock()` method.

```cs
unlocked.DOSizeDelta(Vector2.one, .3f).SetEase(Ease.InBack).onComplete(() => ResetUnlock());
```

Comment: `onComplete(() => ResetUnlock())` and `onComplete(ResetUnlock)` would basically be equivalent just that you introduced a lambda around it

Comment: This is the better option if you are trying to define the logic procedurally and won't necessarily know what you want `OnComplete` to call, but yea for this simple example it will achieve the same result